# iOS 9 Split screen support for iPhone/iPod app

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios9

Is it possible to support iOS 9's multitasking (e.g. split screen) for iPhone/iPod apps as opposed to a Univeral app?

My existing app would need a full UI redesign to look good on an iPad screen, but it would look fine right away on a split screen, which is only half as big.

In my own tests I've only been able to get it to work with a Universal app, but I haven't been able to find any Apple documentation on this yet, so I'm hoping someone here might have some info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to support iOS 9's multitasking (e.g. split screen) for iPhone/iPod apps as opposed to a Universal app?

No.

> I haven't been able to find any Apple documentation on this yet

They're not explicit about it, because it seems obvious on its face, as I think you understand. You can infer it from a few places though. For example [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/AdoptingMultitaskingOniPad/QuickStartForSlideOverAndSplitView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015145-CH13-SW1) says:

> In your project’s `Info.plist` file, in the “Supported interface orientations (iPad)” array, declare support for all four device orientations, as shown here:

It should be obvious that the “Supported interface orientations (iPad)” array won't be read on an iPhone-only app.

Comment: Personally, I think if you're going to honor a question by answering it and then take best answer, perhaps you should EITHER upvote the question or vote to close, perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

This is about device/iOS capabilities (so it's not a dev question per se).

Multitasking is supported on all devices. However, the iPad also adds Slide Over, Split View and Picture in Picture.

> On your iPad, you can use multitasking to switch between apps using gestures, use two apps at once, answer emails while watching a video, and more.

[Source](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202070)